# Oracle PL/SQL - ORA-01403 "No data found" when using "SELECT INTO"

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers, oracle11g

I faced this problem while developing a Trigger in Oracle: [ORA-01403: no data found](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora01403.php). I did some research and understood the root of the problem. Nevertheless [handling the error exception](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/ORA-01403) prevents the above error, but does not solve my problem.

What I am currently looking for is an *optimal* workaround to perform the lesser query amount/achieve the best performance as possible. I'll try to describe the scenario creating simple examples to the real structure.

### Scenario

I have a "date reference" table to establish periods of time, say:

```
CREATE TABLE DATE_REFERENCE (
    DATE_START                  DATE NOT NULL,
    DATE_END                    DATE NOT NULL,
    -- Several other columns here, this is just a silly example
    CONSTRAINT PK_DATE_REFERENCE PRIMARY KEY(DATE_START, DATE_END)
);
```

When the trigger is triggered, I'll have one `DATE` field - say `DATE_GIVEN` (for example sake). What I need is:

1. To find the `DATE_REFERENCE` row in which `DATE_GIVEN BETWEEN DATE_START AND DATE_END` (easy); *OR*
2. If the previous option returns *no data*, I need to find the next closest `DATE_START` to `DATE_GIVEN`.

In both cases, I need to retrieve **the row with all columns** from table `DATE_REFERENCE`, no matter if it matches Opt 1 or 2. That's exactly where I faced the problem described.

I wrote this test block to *test* and try to find a solution. The example below **is not working**, I know; **but it is *exactly* what I want to accomplish** (in concept). I have added comments like `-- Lots of code` to make clear that will be part of a more elaborate trigger:

```
DECLARE
    DATE_GIVEN       DATE; 
    RESULTROW        DATE_REFERENCE%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN

    -- Lots of code
    -- Lots of code
    -- Lots of code

    DATE_GIVEN := TO_DATE('2014-02-26 12:30:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS');

    -- This one throws the ORA-01403 exception if no data was found
    SELECT 
       * INTO RESULTROW
    FROM
       DATE_REFERENCE
    WHERE
       DATE_GIVEN BETWEEN DATE_START AND DATE_END;

    -- If the above didn't throw exceptions, I would continue like so:
    IF RESULTROW IS NULL THEN

        SELECT 
           * INTO RESULTROW
        FROM
           DATE_REFERENCE
        WHERE
           DATE_START > DATE_GIVEN
           AND ROWNUM = 1
        ORDER BY DATE_START ASC;

    END IF;

    -- Now RESULTROW is populated, and the rest of the trigger code gets executed ~beautifully~

    -- Lots of code
    -- Lots of code
    -- Lots of code

END;
```

### Question

Knowing that the above PL/SQL block is more of a ***concept*** than ***working code***, what is the best way to get `RESULTROW` populated, minding performance and the lesser queries as possible?

Sorry for the long question, but I figured scenario explanation was necessary. Thanks in advance for any help/thoughts!

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256112/pl-sql-block-problem-no-data-found on exception handling

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just populate the field directly, using ordering and `rownum`:

```
SELECT * INTO RESULTROW
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM DATE_REFERENCE
      ORDER BY (CASE WHEN DATE_GIVEN BETWEEN DATE_START AND DATE_END
                     THEN 1 ELSE 0
                END) DESC,
               (DATE_START - DATE_GIVEN)
     ) t
WHERE rownum = 1;
```

This will populate the information with one query.

EDIT:

If you want to put a condition in the subquery, it needs to be:

```
SELECT * INTO RESULTROW
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM DATE_REFERENCE
      WHERE DATE_GIVEN <= DATE_END
      ORDER BY (CASE WHEN DATE_GIVEN BETWEEN DATE_START AND DATE_END
                     THEN 1 ELSE 0
                END) DESC,
               (DATE_START - DATE_GIVEN)
     ) t
WHERE rownum = 1;
```

I believe the right condition is `DATE_GIVEN <= DATE_END`.  This covers both the `between` condition and should imply `DATE_GIVEN < DATE_START`.  This assumes that `DATE_END` is never `NULL`.

Comment: I would add `WHERE DATE_END >= DATE_GIVEN` to the inner query. Althougn OP didn't mention the size of table assume this condition may improve performance (not reduce at least).

Comment: Awesome solution, haven't thought of that. It just needs one fix: as @YaroslavShabalin suggested, `WHERE DATE_END >= DATE_GIVEN` not only may improve performance as it **is needed** to pick the correct `DATE_REFERENCE` record. E.g. `(DATE_START - DATE_GIVEN)` may render negative values, so if `BETWEEN` criteria doesn't match, we could get the first period instead of "the next" one.

Comment: @YaroslavShabalin . . . Yes, that condition can be added.  It does assume `DATE_END >= DATE_START`, which is reasonable, and that `DATE_END` is not `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

I also had similar problem, resolved it like this:

if the row does not exists in table `LADDER.INCR_PROCESS` I get `IsPassed` as Null:

```
Declare    
    IsPassed      Integer ;
Begin
    Select I.LVL Into IsPassed 
      From LADDER.INCR_PROCESS  I
      Right 
      Join  Dual   on I.LVL >= 90010  and I.Passed = 0  
     Where RowNum = 1 ;
     ....
End;
```

Answer (score 0):

I just have found new solution:

```
    Declare
        L_ID    Integer;
      Begin
      select 
          (  Select PREFERREDID  from ladder.ric_exceptions where  PREFERREDID  = 1 ) into  L_ID
      from dual;
      end;
```