# PL/SQL Oracle Stored Procedure (No Data Found)

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

**CODE**

```
 -- Stored Procedure 
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DEVELOPMENT_PROCEDURE 
 (
    P_JOB_TYPE IN JOBS.JOB_TITLE%type DEFAULT 'Manager'
  , P_JOB_ID OUT JOBS.JOB_ID%type
  , P_JOB_TITLE OUT JOBS.JOB_TITLE%type
 ) AS 
 BEGIN
   SELECT JOB_ID, JOB_TITLE
   INTO P_JOB_ID, P_JOB_TITLE
   FROM JOBS
   WHERE JOB_TITLE = P_JOB_TYPE;
 END DEVELOPMENT_PROCEDURE;
```

**CODE**

```
-- Calling the Stored Procedure
DECLARE
  P_JOB_ID JOBS.JOB_ID%type;
  P_JOB_TITLE JOBS.JOB_TITLE%type;
  P_JOB_TYPE VARCHAR2(25) := 'Manager';
BEGIN
  DEVELOPMENT_PROCEDURE(P_JOB_TYPE,P_JOB_ID,P_JOB_TITLE);
  SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(P_JOB_ID);
  SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(P_JOB_TITLE);
END;
```

**Problem**

This is the error message I am receiving after running. I am following a tutorial to the letter, but still receiving errors; solved most ... stuck here.

```
ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: at "HR.DEVELOPMENT_PROCEDURE", line 8
ORA-06512: at line 8
```

There is no exception setup, but I should be seeing 15 records. Any ideas?

Could this be an issue with declaration? I need the parameter to read Manager and not MANAGER. Could this be the issue? If so, how can I fix it so the variable read like Manager. Thank you.

As @Drumbeg had pointed out, I am actually pulling too many records, but even after fixing SQL to select single record I am still receiving same error. Could there be an issue with the database itself?

Comment: Your query on the `JOBS` table isn't returning any data. Are you sure that records exist with a `job_title` of `'Manager'`?

Comment: You need to handle NO_DATA_FOUND and TOO_MANY exceptions. Or make sure you always have one matching row for SELECT INTO.

Comment: Hi @PZNevill, where are your exceptions? Look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256112/pl-sql-block-problem-no-data-found

Comment: @Drumbeg Yes, I should see 15 records.

Comment: @Andy K I will look through that answer now. Thank you.

Comment: You're getting `NO DATA FOUND` exception which means that the table might not have any record for `MANAGER`. Can you check the data in your table?

Comment: @Incognito I checked before posting question. Yes, there are 15 records.

Comment: So if you just run SELECT JOB_ID, JOB_TITLE FROM JOBS
   WHERE JOB_TITLE = 'Manager' directly, it returns values?  Does not seem likely.

Comment: I am sure you would have already made sure that there is no difference in case of your input parameter (uppercase/lowercase) from what is stored in the table.

Comment: @OldProgrammer Yet that is what happens ...

Comment: Bear in mind if your query brings back 15 rows, you will get a TOO MANY ROWS exception anyway. At the moment, your code will only work if your query brings back exactly one row. As mentioned, you need to either wrap your query in an exception block or use an explicit `CURSOR` in order to get around this.

Comment: @Drumbeg Ah! That is very True. Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps try to eliminate differences in case/whitespace in your query. `WHERE trim(lower(JOB_TITLE)) = trim(lower(P_JOB_TYPE));`. Just something to try out. Not a permanent solution.

Comment: @Drumbeg That worked for me, but ... it's unclear why. Make comment into answer and I'll accept.

Comment: Does it work if you take out the `lower` and just leave the `trim`? i.e. `WHERE trim(JOB_TITLE) = trim(P_JOB_TYPE)`. Also, what is the datatype of the `JOB_TITLE` column?

Comment: @Drumbeg It works without trim() but not lower(). I am assuming this is because of declaration issues, and has nothing to do with white space; JOB_TITLE is varchar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments above, I think we can deduce there is a difference in case between `P_JOB_TYPE` and the `JOB_TYPE` data for your expected rows in the database, hence why applying `lower()` to both sides of the predicate starts to bring data back.

It's worth pointing out that applying a `lower()` to both sides of the predicate is not a good solution on it's own as there may be performance implications if this is not supported by a functional index. Probably better to be sure of the case you are storing in the database and just apply an `upper()` or `lower()` to the right hand side of the predicate (i.e. `P_JOB_TYPE` side).