# Outputting variable result from Oracle loop

Tags: sql, oracle

I'd like to output `STATEMENT_NUMBER` for each record where `ID` is between 10 and 40

I tried writing the below :-

```
DECLARE
    tempid       NUMBER := 10;
    tempresult   VARCHAR2(20);
BEGIN
    LOOP
        SELECT
            statement_number
        INTO
            tempresult
        FROM
            tblstatementsnew
        WHERE
            id = tempid;

        dbms_output.put_line(tempresult);
        tempid := tempid + 1;
        EXIT WHEN tempid = 40;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

..but I get the error :-

*Cause:    No data was found from the objects.
*Action:   There was no data from the objects which may be due to end of fetch.

I appreciate there are more simple ways of getting these results, but I'm attempting to learn more about how loops work.

Comment: You should handle No data found error properly. See this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/1271985/1352127

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope your code is more complicated than just a print statement.  But, consider using an implicit cursor instead:

```
BEGIN
    FOR v_tempresult IN (SELECT statement_number 
                           FROM tblstatementsnew 
                           WHERE id BETWEEN 10 AND 40)
    LOOP
        dbms_output.put_line(v_tempresult.statement_number);
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: I get a 'TEMPRESULT' must be declared error with this. Must that also be declared?

Comment: + dont forget to [enable the output](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7889380/9338645)!

Comment: hi, can you please take a look at my question? it is similar to trimming last characters. thank you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69834411/update-one-column-of-each-row-in-a-table-pl-sql-unix-scripting